# Unable to disable layer animation - Revolution Slider

Tags: wordpress, animation, revolution-slider

Could you please let me know how to disable layer animation?
I have selected "Fade" for the "Start Transition", and enter the number "0" for the "Start Duration". These settings are working fine in Firefox but isn't working for Chrome browser. Please let me know.

Revolution Slider version - 4.6.5
Rocco theme version - 1.3

Answer (score 7):

If your animation gets stuck, consider checking you animation settings. If you are using revolution slider, change the settings as below. It worked for me!

The slideshow was disappearing after a few seconds of the first slideshow.

[image: first image]
[image: second image]

Answer (score 5):

The next settings for me have worked:
**Go to "Edit slides"**:

- *General setting*: Transitions: no transitions, Rotation: 0, Transition Duration: 0, Delay: empty.
- *Layers timing & sorting*: Start: 0, End: 9000 - for all layers.
- *Layer animation -> Start transition*: Start duration: 0, Split delay: 0 - for all layers.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a specific layer(s) to be static through all slides then take a look at [this documentation page](http://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/second-steps/#staticlayers) and if you are using Revolution Slider below version 5.0 then take a look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5ywH.png).

Here is my detailed answer for Revolution Slider ver 4.6.93 that I am using:

1. On your Slider General Settings find an option "Enable Static Layers" and turn it on, then click Save Settings
2. Click Edit Slides button
3. At the bottom of the page you should now see "Edit Static/Global Layers" button. Click this button and create static elements there. They will be visible on all slides of your slider.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I know I'm a little late to the party, and this response most likely doesn't apply top the version originally posted. This works for version 6. I don't know if this is the way its *supposed* to work, but it *does* work.

Click the GEAR icon, or Module options when editing your slider. Select 'General',and look for "Dynamic Viewport Loading". Turn it ON and set it to WAIT and 0%.

This will stop the animation from playing, allowing you to use your scroll based animations at their correct times, and other cool stuff!

---

[Stop Animation By Setting Dynamic Viewport Loading to On and 0px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CYq0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can set fade -> no transition if it's a background or simple transition -> no animation if it's a simple layer

[screenShot from slider rev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlQOE.jpg)